VmmemWSL consume 100% memory whenever I start Docker and WSL?
I'm facing problem with my docker and wsl, 90-100% memory consumption showing with VmmemWSL
TaskManager processes.
I've tried wsl --shutdown in cmd as administrator it ended the process of wsl but later on docker does not work.
I've tried to edit .wslconfig file with 2 GB memory but that too doesn't work.
Expecting:
solution to VmmemWSL to run at low memory and running docker doesn't get affected.

You cannot shutdown WSL and expect Docker to work as that's a core technology powering it on Windows. Are you sure your .wslconfig was loaded properly? Double check things in this link to make sure.
